# Story where a man meditates his way into a matrix-like reality

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Years ago, I read a short story in which the solitary character was living out his life in his mind. I am left only with the image of the crumbling temple walls around him as he sits still.

I recall this story being recommended to me as thematically suggestive of both The Matrix and Inception.

Comment: Is there anything fantastical or science fictional about this story? As of now it seems rather ordinary.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please take a moment to review the [help] and take the [tour] to learn more about the site. Also, please read through the lists presented [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can think of any additional detail to add that may help us answer your question. If you do think of anything else, be sure to [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/188404/edit) it into your question.